# How is に used in 人に助言をして欲しいタイプ ？

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 人に助言をして欲しいタイプと、人に何かを言われるのが嫌いなタイプの性格の違いは、何でしようか。友人に、人に言われるのが嫌いな人がおられるのですが

I am a bit confused by に here .This sentence: "人に助言をして欲しいタイプ" means the type that wants to be advised by others. Why isn't から used here instead ?
Shouldn't the sujected marked by に be used for passive e.g :に何かを言われる ？why does it not mean people who i want to give advise to ? I am very perplexed .

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding 人に助言をして欲しいタイプ=*the type that want to be advised by others* is correct, but in Japanese 助言をしてほしい is not passive, which may be the source of confusion.

Compare

- 私は彼に助言をしてほしい I want him to advise (to me)

So a more literal translation of 人に助言をして欲しい is *(Subject) wants someone to advise*, so that 人に助言をして欲しいタイプ means *a type of people who wants someone to advise*=*a type of people who wants to be advised*.

Since you can say 誰かから助言が欲しい, から works instead of に, as you guessed.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the に in `～に〜をもらう` or `〜に [V て-form]-もらう`, which also denotes the agent of an action. In fact, you can rephrase 人に助言をして欲しい as 人に助言をしてもらいたい.

人から助言をして欲しい is OK, but it sounds a bit like the speaker wants others to proactively give advice to them. に sounds more neutral without this nuance of “proactive”.